# Is it possible to manipulate the list of page templates?

Tags: theme-development, pages, templates, page-template, template-hierarchy

After answering [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/226269/example-of-a-theme-organization-without-all-the-default-wp-files-in-root) I wondered if it is possible to manipulate the dropdown list of possible page templates that's available when you edit a page. WordPress derives this list from the template files available in the root directory (like `page.php`, `page-onecolumn.php`, `page-about-us.php`). It doesn´t seem to store the list in the database.

I could imagine there are legit reasons to want this, for instance if you have ten page templates, but you want to limit access to some of them for non-admin users. Or perhaps you want to create templates dynamically through an option page, so you want to extend the list.

Comment: [A similar question / answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/182015/7355) sets creates fake Page Templates to act as Post Type Archive landing pages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The workhorse is [`WP_Theme::get_page_templates()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_theme/get_page_templates/) (wrapped by the helper function [`get_page_templates()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_page_templates/)). If you check out the source, you'll see:

```
/**
 * Filter list of page templates for a theme.
 *
 * @since 3.9.0
 * @since 4.4.0 Converted to allow complete control over the `$page_templates` array.
 *
 * @param array        $page_templates Array of page templates. Keys are filenames,
 *                                     values are translated names.
 * @param WP_Theme     $this           The theme object.
 * @param WP_Post|null $post           The post being edited, provided for context, or null.
 */
return (array) apply_filters( 'theme_page_templates', $page_templates, $this, $post );
```

Example:

```
function wpse_226324_page_templates( $templates ) {
    // Remove tpl-home.php template
    unset( $templates['tpl-home.php'] );

    // Add custom template
    $templates['tpl-custom.php'] = 'Custom Template';

    return $templates;
}

add_filter( 'theme_page_templates', 'wpse_226324_page_templates' );
```

See also [`theme_page_templates` code reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/theme_page_templates/).

Comment: That's great. But adding a template still requires a physical file to be present, right?

Comment: Nope - you could then use the `page_template` filter to "inject" a real filepath.